# How to checkout a file in TFS in Visual Studio Single File Generator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, single-file-generator

I am writing a VS Single File Generator for VS 2013. In the generator I am trying to create/modify a new file in the parent folder. If the file which I am trying to create already exists and is read only(source controlled in TFS) then I am getting an error while trying to write anything into it.

I think I need to programmatically checkout the file before editing it. Can someone please provide any pointer on how can I achieve it?

I am also add this new file into the project file, I believe I will have to checkout the project file also before I can add to it.

Comment: As far as I know this should be handled automatically if you're using TFVC with server workspaces within Visual Studio. If the opened solution isn't connected to TFVC and the file is part of a server workspace, then it *should* fail when trying to edit it. Server workspaces work by checking out the file at the time of modification, but Visual Studio naturally has to know where to check the file out from. This is handled by the solution's version control binding.

Comment: What error did you get? Did you handle the file in TFS workspace? You may check `tf checkout` command to see whether it is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/checkout-or-edit-command?view=vsts.

Comment: I got access denied error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by checking if the file being modified is in the Source Control. If it is in the Source Control and not checked out then I checkout the file before trying to modify it. I created a below method in which `dte` is `EnvDTE.DTE`.

```
    private void CheckoutFileIfRequired(string fileName)
    {
        if (dte.SourceControl == null
            || !dte.SourceControl.IsItemUnderSCC(fileName)
                || dte.SourceControl.IsItemCheckedOut(fileName))
        {
            return;
        }
        Action<string> checkOutAction;
        checkOutAction = file => dte.SourceControl.CheckOutItem(file);
        // run on worker thread to prevent the tool calling back into VS
        checkOutAction.EndInvoke(checkOutAction.BeginInvoke(fileName, null, null));
    }
```